# How to make sure that the request using cURL was actually sent/received

Tags: laravel, curl, esp8266

I have a simple Intranet set up with **1 router**, **1 computer**, and **10 ESP8266**.
I have a Laravel app served on that computer that sends Get Request to an ESP8266 module locally.
After a successful request, ESP8266 needs to activate some hardware and the Laravel app needs to update the database that the request was actually sent.

I have a simple cURL like below:

```
$url = "$machine->ip_address/activate";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
$curl_error = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if($curl_error) {
  // rollback the database
} else {
  // update the database that the request was actually sent/received
}
```

In my ESP8266, I have this code snippet

```
void handleRequest() {
  // some logic to activate the hardware
  server.send(200, "text/html", "1");
}
```

The snippet above and the cURL work just fine. But there are times that the cURL failed to receive the response from ESP8266 but the hardware was activated. That means that the request was sent, but the response wasn't received. In that instance, the device will be activated but the database will not be updated. Because the Laravel app would believe that the request was not sent/received.

TLDR: How can I make sure that the request actually failed/succeeded?

Do I need some configuration for the router to make it more stable?

Comment: If you're using Laravel, I would suggest to use their HTTP Client instead of managing curl requests manually. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client

Comment: One of the reasons that MQTT is popular in IoT applications is that it provides the [QoS](https://learn.adafruit.com/alltheiot-protocols/mqtt-qos) for the data sent